# solution to backup postgresql alongside with file system

Tags: postgresql, filesystems, backup, database-backups

I'm developing an application with a postgresql db. Also it stores files in file system and keep their address in the db. I want an open source solution for backing up the app state including database and file storages.
Mandatory requirements:

- supports backing up postgresql db when it is running.
- support becking up a folder
- support compression

Optional requirements:

- Can view, create and restore backups in a web console.(Important)
- support plugins or custom backup/restore tasks
- support other data storages like mysql
- support retention

I've seen project like [barman](http://www.pgbarman.org/) or [amanda](http://amanda.zmanda.com/) but It seems each one solve some part of the problem.
Should I develop the solution myself?
The application is developed in java, if it matters.

Comment: What's your OS? And how large would your database be?

Comment: The os is linux(debian 7.5) and the database is not so large! all datas on it will be less than 1GB.